# How to submit UWP application via API

Tags: uwp, continuous-deployment

I have a UWP application that is deployed manually to the Microsoft Store (using the Partner Center).
Each time I have a new version of the app to deploy I have to go to the Partner Center, provide information, upload the new file and start the process of creating a new Submission for the app.

I'm wondering if there is a way to automate this process.
I mean for example upload the file via ftp and fills up the relevant information via API.
These would be fantastic and it would allow me to setup a Continuous Deployment process.

Is there any chance to overcome the manual process?

Thanks
\sergio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the `Microsoft Store submission API` could programmatically query and create submissions for apps, add-ons and package flights for your Partner Center account. This API is useful if your account manages many apps or add-ons, and you want to automate and optimize the submission process for these assets.

You could check this document about how to use it: [Create and manage submissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/create-and-manage-submissions-using-windows-store-services).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll check in the link you suggested me.